# Fluent nHibernate Configuration

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to configure fluent nHibernate and have this code

```
Assembly mappingAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom("LibrarySample.Model.dll");
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
     .ConnectionString(c => c
        .FromAppSetting("ConnectionString"))
     .ShowSql())
   .Mappings(m => m
     .FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly))
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

When I run I get this message though "FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory".

If I use this code it works, but I don't want to reference the Model assembly directly from the Core assembly that has the nHibernate session manager.

```
sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
     .ConnectionString(c => c
        .FromAppSetting("ConnectionString"))
     .ShowSql())
   .Mappings(m => m
     .FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<LibrarySample.Model.Book>())
   .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 8):

I worked it out. One of the properties in the Entity class was not marked as virtual.

Comment: Didn't understand, why? Isn't making properties virtual enough?